# Compare Configurations within Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration

Actually i come around a problem i get more often into as i like to:

Consider the following:
You just made a new solution/project and start creating/adding all the stuff you need. While you're doing so, you're always on the way within the debug configuration. You make changes to your configuration (in C++ projects especially compiler, linker settings) and at the end of the day you just want to swap to release mode to make a final build and what happens?? You got plenty of error messages about missing defines, linked libraries, preprocessor definitions, precompiled headers, etc.)

And now? You open the Project Properties, select each item in the tree view and switch for and back with the combo box of the Configuration at the top left.

Due to the fact, that both configurations are saved within one file you can't also use a simple Diff-Tool or you have to copy and paste both parts out of the project file into two different files, compare them and merge everything back into the project file.

Isn't there a better solution to compare different configurations within one project??

Comment: While you're looking for the after-thought solution, this is what I do to avoid this problem in the first place: Whenever I change anything in the configuration, I select _All configurations_. This is fine for most available settings, especially for things like Linker and Include settings.

Comment: You're right. I will already use *All configurations*, but sometimes i just missed out and after a while i just realize, that i'm not able to get all configurations successfully build and then the damn work of manually comparing configuration starts ...

Comment: I've become so frustrated with this problem that I'm thinking of writing a tool to parse a project file and compare various values between the different configurations.  Did you ever find a solution (so I don't have to write my own tool)?

Comment: @aldo: Unfortunately this question has no accepted answer tag for a good reason: Till today i didn't found a satisfying solution. I'm hoping all the time that someone will integrate this feature into Visual Studio (native or as extension) or into SharpDevelop, but with no luck till today.

Comment: maybe apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619146/vimdiff-two-subroutines-in-same-file

Comment: Good question, yesterday I had very "productive" day spending all the time configuring projects:
Debug/Win32
Release/Win32
Test/Win32
Debug/x64
Release/x64
Test/x64
And even coffee didn't help me not to fall asleep at my desk :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure when they introduced it, but in VS2015 at-least, you can select "Multiple Configurations..." in the configuration drop-down list on the Property Pages screen. You can then select "All Options" from the various sections, and see which parameters differ (those that differ say ). Doesn't show you the actual values - you still have to switch back and forth for that - but at least you can spot the differences quickly.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth now, here's how I handle the problem of changing one configuration and forgetting to change the other. This process that I use, however, does have two caveats: 1) it works with VS2010 and above; and, 2) I've learned to avoid that problem altogether.

First off, I *NEVER* make changes to the project's property page itself! They tend to use build conditions that causes this problem in the first place. Instead, I always have my "Property Manager" opened beside my "Solution Explorer".

Second, I have several "pre-defined" property sheets in a sub-folder called common.properties that I include from, for instance:

- my_macros.props - common macro definitions specific to my solution's (read: framework) directory structure. For example, I have a definition called MY_COMMON_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY that equals $(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(ProjectName).
- my_dox_settings.props - Settings specific to doxygen projects. Yep, I create a seperate project using doxygen to create my documentation.
- my_test_settings.props - Settings specific for my unit-testing framework. Again, a seperate project for unit-tests. Adds a post-build event that runs the compiled executable.
- my_app_settings.props - Default settings for my application's framework. For instance, it sets the "output directory" to the previously mentioned MY_COMMON_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.
- my_app_settings_use_pch.props - Additional changes to my application's framework that uses precompiled-headers. It simply adds a /DI_WANT_MY_PCH compiler switch.
- include_boost_files.props - Settings for adding the boost-libraries to my projects.
- include_ogre_files.props - Settings for adding ogre-libraries to my projects.
- include_sdl_file.props - Setting for adding sdl-libraries to my projects.
- You should be getting the idea...

Next, I create a NEW blank property sheet and add it as well. I typically call this $(ProjectName).props [NOTE: be sure to expand the macro yourself] and then add it via the property manager as the very last item.

Now, when I need to make a change to the project, I just simply flip over to the property-manager and change the appropriate property-sheet. Keep in mind that doing so affects all projects that use that property-sheet. If you only want to affect your current project, then modify the $(ProjectName) property-sheet. Unless you build in conditions (which I won't get into), one change affects many configurations (and projects).

I even check my common.properties directory into source-control.

I hope this helps,

Comment: Sounds like a quite good idea. I never worked with self-defined property pages (cause i didn't know about them). Nut it sounds like its worth to take a deeper look.

Comment: So how has this solution turned out for you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a perfect solution to compare within a project file... but for what it's worth, you may find it helpful to compare the current project file to the copy in source control.  And then where you see a changed value in one section, you can quickly see whether that value is also changed in the other section.

But your question specified a new project... so I'll assume it isn't in source control yet.

So here's another option: Copy the project file to another name and then compare the two copies.  Yes, they'll be the same... but if you use a good tool such as Beyond Compare 2 that allows you to manually align sections then you can right click on the first line of the debug section in the left window and select Align Manually and then right click on the first line of the release section in the right window and select Align Manually.  Voila... there are your changes.  :)

Comment: These are quite good options and i already try to do this stuff more or less these ways, but they feel uncomfortable and ugly. Especially the usage of diff tools (even the VS built-in version for source control) just shows that the tools are already there.

All we need is a mechanism, that splits up the xml file correctly to show two versions (eg debug, release) beside each other and that you don't have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

There's a program called BeyondCompare3 that is very cheap.  I rarely endorse products, but it should do the job for you here.  Use the "Compare selection to clipboard" option.

Comment: As i already said, i try to accomplish these tasks with an external diff tool. But it just feels so uncomfortable to open the raw xml files and manually align the two sections, so that the diff tool compare these two sections.

Comment: Did you use this specific tool?  There is a lot of variation between diff tools.  With BeyondCompare 3, you just highlight the areas to be compared.  It still takes effort, but not as much as aligning.

If you are looking for automagic "fix my configuration" answer, you're going to have to write it yourself.  It's a small enough problem that there aren't going to be tons of people out there writing a utility, free or otherwise, to address it.