# How to ‘diff’ two subroutines in the same file in Vim?

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

Is it possible to `diff` or even `vimdiff` two very similar subroutines occurring in the same file? If so, how?

I can think of copying the two subroutines in two separate files and then `diff` them, but is there a way to do it within the original file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot do this within the original file, but you can do this without using separate files, only separate buffers. This should work if you copied one subroutine in register `a` (for example, with `"ay` typed in Visual mode) and other subroutine in register `b`:

```
enew | call setline(1, split(@a, "\n")) | diffthis | vnew | call setline(1, split(@b, "\n")) | diffthis
```

To automate:

```
let g:diffed_buffers = []

function DiffText(a, b, diffed_buffers)
    enew
    setlocal buftype=nowrite
    call add(a:diffed_buffers, bufnr('%'))
    call setline(1, split(a:a, "\n"))
    diffthis
    vnew
    setlocal buftype=nowrite
    call add(a:diffed_buffers, bufnr('%'))
    call setline(1, split(a:b, "\n"))
    diffthis
endfunction

function WipeOutDiffs(diffed_buffers)
    for buffer in a:diffed_buffers
        execute 'bwipeout! ' . buffer
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap <special> <F7> :call DiffText(@a, @b, g:diffed_buffers)<CR>
nnoremap <special> <F8> :call WipeOutDiffs(g:diffed_buffers) | let g:diffed_buffers=[]<CR>
```

Note that you may want to set `hidden` option if Vim refuses to abandon changed file (see `:h abandon`).

Comment: This works great but I keep getting "No buffers were wiped out: bwitpeout! 2" (the number changes) when I call WipeOutDiffs via f8.  What's causing this?  Thanks!!

Comment: This is a cool answer. many thanks.

Answer (score 53):

Plugin [linediff.vim : Perform an interactive diff on two blocks of text](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3745) is similar to the one pointed ou by Vincent with some additional features:

- has a command to close the opened buffer
- seems to work without GUI
- insert some visual indication on the original file(s) being diffed.

To use it you perform a visual selection on the first block to diff, enter command `:Linediff`, and repeat it to the second block. To quit, `:LineDiffReset`

I've found the followings maps helpful:

```
noremap <leader>ldt :Linediff<CR>
noremap <leader>ldo :LinediffReset<CR>
```

Comment: This plugin works very well.  It is documented and maintained in git.  It highlights the selected blocks in the original files.  It does not require gvim.  I can't see how it could be improved, and in my opinion it is the best solution.  Please try it and vote up.

Comment: This link appears to have died in the 11 years since this answer was posted. But could it be the same thing as [AndrewRadev/linediff.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim)?

Answer (score 7):

You can write those two parts/subroutines/sections to two files and then use vimdiff to see the difference.

```
    :1, 39 write part1          //any line range or marks can be used
    :40, 79 write part2
    :!vimdiff part1 part2
```

If you aren't comfortable with using line numbers, you can keep the cursor at start of the section , press v and select till the end of the section and then press : . it will show :'<,'>. Then type write and then file name in the command line itself. Press enter.  Similary, do for second one also. Then you can execute vimdiff command as stated above.

(Write command saves the part to a new file.)
Writing a new file may not be a good idea, but that helps me. Especially when we had to go through the comparison several times.

This is one of the simplest way without using plugin or if you aren't concerned about memory.

Answer (score 3):

I really like ZyX's answer, but needed to make two modifications for it to work seamlessly:

1. As implemented, <F7> replaces the active buffer with the vertically split diff display.  Then, while <F8> closes the diff, it does not reload the original buffer.  To fix this, I changed `enew` on the third line to `execute 'tab split | enew'`.
2. In order to minimize side-effects, I added `call remove(a:diffed_buffers, 0, -1)` just before the end of WipeOutDiffs().

HTH,
- Stu

Comment: I wish you would post your complete file. I don't have any errors so I am not certain if these changes are already present or vim changed over the years to make them irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this command:

```
vimdiff <(cat file.foo | sed -n 10,15p) <(cat file.foo | sed -n 20,25p)
```

Where the numbers fed to `sed` are the line number I want to diff in the file. `<(*)` means evaluate and redirect as input.

Comment: reading this after a while, still wondering why I used `cat`... leaving it out should also work: `vimdiff <(sed -n 10,15p file.foo) <(sed -n 20,25p file.foo)`

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Block diff vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2048), it will make 2 new buffer in a new tab to show the differences.

Comment: I saw its code: it does almost exactly what my solution above does, but it is not able to close opened buffers by pressing one key.

Comment: Very nice, but it only works when you have a GUI, which is not always my case when I work on a remote server. So, I chose to accept the answer by ZyX. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually it does work on the non-GUI version of vim (using vim 7.3).  It uses the non-GUI tab implementation, maybe that wasn't present when the plugin was written so now it just works?