# How to compare two unsaved pieces of texts in Vim?

Tags: vim

What I want to do is: 
(1) Copy a piece of code and paste into a buffer in Vim;
(2) Copy another piece of code and paste into another buffer in Vim; 
(3) Compare these two buffers directly without saving them into files.

I know this can be done easily with Notepad++. I need to do this quite often, and I want to know if Vim can do this. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Vim)diff two subroutines in same file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619146/vimdiff-two-subroutines-in-same-file)

Comment: For the case where the text is already in some other vim buffer or buffers I'd suggest BlockDiff plugin, which is covered at the link ZyX gives.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `:diffthis` on each window you want to compare.

See `:help diff`.

Comment: If you have just those two buffers open then execute `:windo difft`. This will execute `:difft` on each window.