# Visual Studio 2017 .net core project bootstrapper error when adding wcf endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.2, bootstrapper

In **ASP.NET Core 2.2 Class Library Project**, I'm trying to update a service in ***Connected Services*** which is already added.

**Problem Statement:**

When I try to update/add WCF Service I face below error (snapshot is added below in the question). it appears to be some issue with bootstrapper. but error message is not that clear to understand the issue.

Example Endpoint URL: http://mywebApp.com/AppServices/ExampleService/DService.svc

**What I have tried:**

- End Point URL works.
- Same project is opened in VS 2010 and VS 2019 WCF End Point was added successfully.
- and in my colleagues everyone is able to add this WCF service in VS 2017 and same project.

**So I came to know this, that issue in my vs 2017 settings or bootstrapper**

**Any help would be much appriciated**

[image]

Comment: First you can compare the VS configuration on a successful computer to your own, and then check the bootstrapper.

Comment: @Jiayao Please explain, how can I compare VS configuration?

Comment: You can try the method in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465654/compare-configurations-within-visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

There is no WCF in .NET Core developed by Microsoft, it is available only in .NET Framework. You can use gRPC or [`CoreWCF`](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF)

Comment: Core Class Library Project
and in my colleagues everyone is able to add this WCF service in VS 2017 and same project.

Comment: maybe they use `.NET framework` instead. or they are using CoreWCF. There is no WCF in `.NET Core`.

Comment: it is same project, from Version Control. no doubt in that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).